# Standardized LASSO in R still has intercept

Tags: r, lasso, standardization, glmnet, intercept

I understand the need to standardize variables when performing LASSO in R (I'm specifically using `cv.glmnet`, and setting `standardize=TRUE`).

The resulting model, however, still fits an intercept. From what I understand, we center the data so that there's no intercept and the model has more freedom to fit coefficients (without the intercept taking up some of the $\Sigma{\beta_j}$), am I doing this correctly? Do I need to set `intercept=FALSE`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The intercept should generally only be omitted if all the predictors ***and*** the response have mean=0 (in which case the intercept must necessarily be 0).

Setting `standardize=TRUE`, which is the default option for `glmnet::glmnet`, only standardizes the predictors. The function has another parameter to standardize the response, but by default this is set to `standardize.response=FALSE`. So you *would* want to estimate an intercept unless you have specified `standardize.response=TRUE`.